# not able to use calls in Fragment ever thought i import the corresponding library

Tags: android

SO here is my understanding of the purpose of importing fragment library(the v4.jar).
Because the developer wants to use and follow the new Fragment's way of coding, but using this will result compatibility issue on older devices that runs on android 2.xx, therefore, in the project that uses fragment, the developer has to import the v4.jar library so that the older devices know what fragment APIs and are able to call them in the app.
If this is correct, I suppose after importing the library, the android:minSdkVersion should be able to set to older version such as 8 (93% of the market), not l0, because the project had already import the library.

But When I am using the method from the fragment, for example, the instantiate method, I got this error:

Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.app.Fragment#instantiate

So apparent the sdk wants me to switch my android:minSdkVersion to 11, but then what is the purpose of importing the library? And by doing so older device that running on android 2.xx will not be able to use this app. 
Can someone explain this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're importing the wrong `Fragment` library.

This one requires API level 11 (Android 3.0):
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

This one, as available in the support library, requires API level 4 (Android 1.6):
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html

Also, you should be aware that you need to use the `FragmentManager` available in the support library.

There are no drawbacks to using the support `Fragment` APIs on Android 3.0+.